# Where are the svn hook files located?

Tags: vb.net, svn

I'm a new intern at a software company and my boss asked me to change the hook code or the post-commit operation in svn tortoise. But I don't now where is the visual basic source code file. Where is it located ? thank you

Comment: I think you might want to look on the svn server for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hooks are generally located in the ROOT_OF_SVN_REPO/hooks directory. There will *.tmpl for many of pre, post operations on the repository.

```
C:\MyRepo\hooks:
 |- post-commit.tmpl
 |- post-lock.tmpl
 |- post-revprop-change.t
 |- post-unlock.tmpl
 |- pre-commit.tmpl
 |- pre-lock.tmpl
 |- pre-revprop-change.tm
 |- pre-unlock.tmpl
 |- start-commit.tmpl
```

You need to create a copy of the .tmpl file without the extension

```
C:\Temp\hooks>copy post-commit.tmpl post-commit
        1 file(s) copied.
```

Then edit it to call the scripts that contain the validation logic, i.e replace the following line at the end of post-commit

```
mailer.py commit "$REPOS" "$REV" /path/to/mailer.conf
```

with

```
cscript my-post-commit.vbs "$REPOS" "$REV" <other args>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What do you mean by :"edit it to call the scripts that contain the validation logic"

Comment: updated my response with what I mean about "edit it..."